# Angular Object literal braces in HTML in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm facing a "problem", it's not a problem just disturbing, in WebStorm.

When in HTML file I've an Object Literal expression like below with many space/tabs on the same line before/after expression, reformat doesn't work.

```html
<div>{{test}}        </div>
```

Same if it's too long, it doesn't wrap correctly, and made some strange formatting.

```html
<div>{{verylongobjctliteralexpression}} 
</div>
```

It's like it doesn't recognize the `{{}}` in html or something like that :/

I've check every settings concerning HTML in CodeStyle section in the Settings but doesn't find anything. I've the default plugin for Angular but no special menu for it...

Answer (score 0):

In your file press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L`.

Reformat dialog will show. There you can config how the reformat occur in the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it doesn't work as expected...